# Emacs Consistently Crashes when Scrolling Remote Files using Tramp

Tags: tramp, crash, scroll

Whenever I scroll using the trackpad in a remote file, Emacs consistently crashes. (Also, other things crash Emacs in remote files, but this is the most common one I've come across)

I have tried Emacs v27 and v26.3 and have seen no difference. I've cleaned up my entire init file and left only tramp in there. Here is what it looks like

```
;; Initialize Package Archives

(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)


;; Install Straight & Use-Package

(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

(straight-use-package 'use-package)


;; Install & Configure tramp

(use-package tramp
  :straight t
  :config
  (setq
   tramp-default-host "ss_analytics"
   tramp-default-method "ssh"
   tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options ""))
```

Error report

https://pastebin.com/uy173Z2n

I love emacs but this is stopping me from being able to use is since 95% of my editing and compiling is remote.

Comment: I'd suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Just did... Thanks

Comment: Just switched to emacs-mac-port. It solved this tramp problem and a fullscreens company-box issue I've been having

Comment: there are several bug reports about crashes of Emacs 27.0.50 in combination of macOS and Tramp. Since they are reported only for macOS, this must be something related.